# Fastest way to add tests that fail for testing to a go project?

Tags: go

I want to add tests to a Go project and have them fail when I run `go test ./...`.

This is only for testing purposes. What is the minimum I need to add to my project to get failing tests?

Comment: Just call any of the Error* Fail* or Fatal* methods in the test (or even panic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to a `*_test.go` file, ie. `fail_test.go`:

```
func TestWillFail(t *testing.T) {
    t.Errorf("This test will fail.")
}
```